# Windows8 - Metro - WebView - NavigateToString disturbs scrolling in Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I encountered this very disturbing bug in our Windows 8 Metro Style application.

We have a grid consisting of three rows
 - A header
 - A listview (containing blocks that lets the user scroll horisontally)
 - A footer (containing a WebView that displays an ad).

..............................................................................
                                   Logo
..............................................................................
ListView
Scrolls horisontally ---------------------->

..............................................................................
                                    AD
..............................................................................

The problem is - when I load the content for the ad (using NavigateToString, which loads some javascript that displays an ad), the scrolling in the listview stops working (unless you use the scrollbar). I have isolated the error to this specific method - if I don't call NavigateToString, but still include the WebView - the scrolling works.

I have tried generating the Html as a Task, and calling the method on the dispatcher, without luck.

I have tried strange stuff, like using a DispatchtTimer to delay the loading of the ad. It works.. until the NavigateToString-method is called.

A strange thing - the view contains a bottom-app-bar. If I show/hide this app-bar, the scrolling suddenly works. (Maybe the focus is somehow regained to the ListView when doing this specific action)..

Any suggestions? =)

Answer (score 2):

Set IsEnabled=false; on the ad control. That's the suggested workaround from the Microsoft ad team for now. Only disadvantage is that users cannot tab to the ad with that set, but I think that's acceptable

Answer (score 0):

The WebView shouldn't be placed in the AppBar and the Visibility must set to Visible.
I've set the Margins of the WebView to the large negative values to hide it out of the application.

Answer (score 0):

add navigationCompleted event to webview and set focus to listview in navigation completed event.

Comment: You should try providing a working example instead of using pseudo-code.